# SDK mangager wont start in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

When I click the "Android SDK Manager" button in Eclipse it will not start. I get this in the console:

[SDK Manager] 'C:\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

[SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.

If I click SDKmanger.exe directly from explorer it works but not from inside eclipse.
How do I solve this? Guessing it have something with a missing PATH variable but have not figured it out. But Im not sure. Have tested to add some but guessing I do it wrong or have added the wrong paths. Or is it something else I have to do?

(If it helps. I have made a new install on win8 with eclipse (for java dev - kepler 4.3), downloaded the android SDK 22.3 added the android ADT plugin in eclipse and added the location to the SDK in preferences. Have installed java 1.7 too.)

=== update ===

Which PATHs is nesecary?
I have already added this to test...

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\

C:\ ...\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;

C:\ ...\android-sdk-windows\tools;

C:\ ...\android-sdk-windows;

but it would not work. Do I miss any?

...

I have added the adress to the sdk folder "android-sdk-windows" to "SDK Location:" under android in prefereces too.

Answer (score 0):

you may have this problem if adb tool has moved to platform-tools/
please update your PATH environment variable to include the platform-tools/ directory, so you can execute adb from any location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the sdk path in Eclipse ?
Go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Browse

And select the sdk folder...

Hope it helps.